# How do you change the same background color on all forms?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm working on this project and I required to allow the user to select a color from the color picker and then it changes into the current form's background, the code I used is:

```
Dim cd As New ColorDialog()
        If cd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Me.BackColor = cd.Color
        End If
```

This code works fine, but it only changes the current form background color, how will I make it so it changes the background colour of all the forms in the project eg Form 1,2 and 3 at the same time.

Comment: There are many ways this can be accomplished, at this point its broad and would generate opinionated answers. Can you please update the post so we can help you.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I understand is quiet broad, which will be the easiest code to do so?

Comment: Loop through open forms, but that will not help if you create a new instance, that would have to be addressed as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Module to your project, then create a global variable to hold the selected color:

```
Module Module1
    Public FormBackColor As Color = SystemColors.Control
End Module
```

When you select a new color, store it there.  Additionally, loop through all open forms via `Application.OpenForms`, and change their color:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim cd As New ColorDialog()
    If cd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        FormBackColor = cd.Color

        For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms
            frm.BackColor = FormBackColor
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

For all forms, add a line in the `Load()` event that sets the color to the current color.  This will make it so that new forms will load with the current color as well:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.BackColor = FormBackColor
End Sub
```

Comment: If you need this to work across runs, then create an entry in Project --> Settings and store the color there.

Comment: What happens if per say maybe a form/s are on another thread, does this still work? More than likely not, you would need to invoke; the lovely drawback of working with the UI...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Why would you have a form running on a different thread?...that shouldn't be done; you deserve the headache if you do it that way.  How about we cover the **basics** first, and worry about rare/edge cases later?

Comment: Good question but a probability right? What about a long running operation and user wants to show progress that indeed is a form? By the way good answer, I hope the user finds it useful as it addresses their issue.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I hear ya.  It just seems like lately that any answer posted here on SO immediately gets shot down because it doesn't cover absolutely **every possibility**.  I thought we were supposed to be helping with specific problems, in bite sized pieces; not publishing an entire book that covers everything from A to Z on how to program in any environment.  << steps back off soap box >>.

Comment: I understand, but the actual question is broad and is opinionated in general which can generate many possible answers. As the question stands its honestly not even enough to answer correctly, jmho and why I didnt provide an answer.

Comment: @Idle_Mind THANK YOU SO MUCH. Yep that works! Yh threading should be an issue to tackle later as this was a small program. I have gave you a positive and correct answer point to compensate it.

Comment: Btw in order for the colour to change as in the colour picker the line where you said `frm.BackColor = FormBackColor` should be `frm.BackColor = cd.Color`. But I have changed it as a edit.

Comment: It should still work as I had it written, since just before that I did `FormBackColor = cd.Color`.  So the color was stored in the module, then the forms backcolor was being set to the stored color...

Comment: @Idle_Mind one quick question, so I have used in my Form1 a User control that its made as a child from the main Form1 Parent. So basically any new forms I open are opened within Form1, how would I change this code to do it for all User controls instead of just for forms, as the current thing i get is something like the one in the link. https://pasteboard.co/I6EWMi8.png

Comment: UserControls, by default, will take the color of their parent (the form in this case).  So the easiest solution would be to go into each of your UserControl(s) and delete whatever color you've set for the BackColor property so it resets to the default "Control" color.  Then they will automatically take on the new color of the form when it gets changed.

Comment: @Idle_Mind Yh I have tried that, I have removed the colour and left it as "BackColor Control", still doesnt change it.

Comment: Let's eliminate your current UserControl as the issue.  Create a new UserControl with nothing in it.  Just set the border so you can see where it is.  Add one to form and see if the skeleton UserControl changes color with the form as expected.

Comment: @Idle_Mind, You the MAN!, so I created a new Form1 User Control, and yep it changes all the colour scheme skeleton and form. Any idea why is not doing it for my project. Is it to do with the User Control im using?

Comment: I'm running a sql query inside my child UserControl, does that affect it? I doubt so tho

Comment: I doubt that's it.  Make sure you cleared the BackColor property; **highlight the value and then hit backspace**.  If you set it to "Control", then it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a setting called BackColor. Do so by going to:

```
Project -> Properties -> Settings.
```

Then create the setting:

```
Put the Name you'd like

Type as String

Scope as User
```

Then in your code put this:

```
Dim cd As New ColorDialog()
        If cd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            Me.BackColor = cd.Color
            My.Settings.BackColor = cd.color
            My.Settings.Save()
        End If
```

Then on each form load put this code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.BackColor = My.Settings.BackColor
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it but it, but this only works if you close and open the program again, not on run time

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with an MDI parent form then you can loop through all child forms and change the backColor.

Comment: Dim newPanel As New frmAdminPanel Me.Parent.Controls.Add(newPanel) newPanel.Top = 100 newPanel.Left = 20 Me.Hide()   This is the parent panel im using, but how would I do what you trying to say?

Comment: Something like this

` Dim parentForm As New Form`
` parentForm.IsMdiContainer = True ' assuming this is your parent form (MDI)`
` Dim form1 As New Form With {.MdiParent = parentForm}`
`Dim form2 As New Form With {.MdiParent = parentForm}`
`Dim form3 As New Form With {.MdiParent = parentForm}`
`' Note : You can't change the background-color of the ParentForm`
`For Each f As Form In parentForm.MdiChildren`
`f.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue ' specify your color here`
`Next`